# PHP - Create a json file from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I know my code below isn't the best way of doing what i'm trying to do here, but I need a way to remove just the double quotes from the key values only using PHP. I need to keep the double quotes inside the "src attribute" though!

### Here is my PHP code:

```
$host = "localhost"; //Your database host server
$db = "root"; //Your database name
$user = "root"; //Your database user
$pass = "1234"; //Your password

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if(!$dbconnect)
    {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM playlist_builder";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

        $records = array();
        $response = array(); //extra            

        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
            $records[] = $r;   
        }

        //Output the data as JSON
        $json = json_encode($records, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        $json = str_replace('\\', '', $json);
        $json = preg_replace('/"([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)":/','$1:',$json);
        // $json = str_replace('"', "'", $json);



        //NOTE: FOLDERS 'url' and 'file' SHOULD BE WRITABLE WITH PERMISSIONS - 777
        //IN CASE 'url' FOLDER PLACED IN SERVER'S ROOT
        //IF YOU'RE USING SOME FTP BROWSER CHANGE PERMISSIONS FOR 'url' 
        //FOLDER AND APPLY IT TO ALL ENCLOSED ITEMS


        $data = 'var data = [{ tags: '; 
        $end = '}];';

        $script = "// Call Slider function
                    $(window).load(function () {
                      $('#slideshow-slider').jSonSlider({
                        'loadallslides': false,
                        'auto': [true, '14000'],
                        'nextprev': false,
                        'circular': true,
                        'pagi': false,
                        'data': data
                      });
                    });";

        file_put_contents('records.js', $data);
        file_put_contents('records.js', $json, FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents('records.js', $end,  FILE_APPEND);
        file_put_contents('records.js', $script, FILE_APPEND);

    }
}
```

### Here is my Output of my js file:

```
var data = [{ tags: [
    {
        id: "1",
        volume: "volume1",
        name: "a",
        content: "<img src="../../../image1.jpg">",
        css_animate: "fadeIn"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        volume: "volume1",
        name: "a",
        content: "<img src="../../../image2.jpg">",
        css_animate: "fadeIn"
    },
    {
        id: "3",
        volume: "volume1",
        name: "a",
        content: "<img src="../../../image3.jpg">",
        css_animate: "fadeIn"
    }
]}];


// Call Slider function     
$(window).load(function () {
   $('#slideshow-slider').jSonSlider({
   'loadallslides': false,
   'auto': [true, '14000'],
   'nextprev': false,
   'circular': true,
   'pagi': false,
   'data': data
  });
});
```

Any help is really appreciated! :)

Comment: Even if you will have quotes everywhere, your json will work. So, now you do useless job.

Comment: You can't, as that denotes that they are strings. And you're screwing up your json by removing the slash that escapes those double-quotes.

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** _mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use `Collection` that comes with `illuminate/support` package. You can pass your associative array to the `Collection's` constructor, then `map` through it and return as `json`.

Example would be:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

$collection = new Collection($records);

$json = $collection->map(function(array $record) {

    return [
        id => $record['id'],
        volume: $record['volume'],
        name: $record['name'],
        content: '<img src="../../../'.$record['image'].'">',
        css_animate: "fadeIn"
    ];

})->toJson();
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are converting a PHP array to JSON, and then converting that JSON to Javascript object. Why don't we let Javascript itself convert the JSON to a JS object? Like this:

```
// JSONify $records. We need the slashes for the
// string to work correctly in Javascript.
$jsonRecords = addslashes(json_encode($records));

// This is the JS file contents (using PHP's heredoc string syntax).
// The $jsonRecords string is inserted as part of that JSON string.
$fileContents = <<<DOC
var data = JSON.parse("[{\"tags\": $jsonRecords }]");

// Call Slider function
$(window).load(function () {
  $('#slideshow-slider').jSonSlider({
    'loadallslides': false,
    'auto': [true, '14000'],
    'nextprev': false,
    'circular': true,
    'pagi': false,
    'data': data
  });
});
DOC;

// Create a file and write to it once.
file_put_contents('records.js', $fileContents);
```

We convert `$records` to JSON and insert it inside a JSON string (`var data`), which is parsed by Javascript's `JSON.parse` function. Now we don't have any troubles with quotes.